# Assigning the numbers and summarising the number of counts in a sliding window in R

Tags: r, sliding-window, rollapply

I have a `df` that looks like this:

```
 df <- (c( "P", "S", "E", "G", "R", "Q", "P", "S", "P", "S", "P", "S", "P", "T", "E", "R", "A", "P", "A", 
"S", "E", "E", "E", "F", "Q", "F", "L", "R", "C", "Q", "Q", "C", 
"Q", "A", "E", "A", "K", "C", "P", "K", "L", "L", "P", "C", "L"))
```

and a `df1` that looks like this:

```
df1
    1     2     3     4     5     
A   0.375 0.000 0.250 0.250 0.125 
C   0.200 0.000 0.600 0.000 0.000 
D   0.000 0.500 0.000 0.400 0.500 
E   0.225 0.250 0.125 0.125 0.000 
F   0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
G   0.000 0.400 0.250 0.000 0.125 
H   0.500 0.000 0.300 0.020 0.000 
I   0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.300 
K   0.000 0.280 0.000 0.125 0.000 
L   0.000 0.000 0.125 0.125 0.125 
M   0.600 0.700 0.000 0.030 0.000 
N   0.000 0.000 0.030 0.000 0.500 
P   0.000 0.000 0.000 0.125 0.125 
Q   0.400 0.165 0.125 0.000 0.250 
R   0.030 0.000 0.125 0.500 0.125 
S   0.350 0.450 0.400 0.000 0.125 
T   0.000 0.000 0.000 0.125 0.000 
V   0.625 0.125 0.400 0.525 0.100 
W   0.400 0.300 0.000 0.000 0.000 
Y   0.125 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
NIL    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   

dput(df1)
    structure(c(0.375, 0.200, 0, 0.225, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.4, 
    0.03, 0.35, 0, 0.625, 0.4, 0.125, NA, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.28, 
    0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0.165, 0, 0.45, 0, 0.125, 0.3, 0, NA, 0.25, 0.6, 0, 0.125, 
    0, 0.25, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.03, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0.4, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 
    NA, 0.25, 0, 0.4, 0.125, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0.03, 0, 0.125, 
    0, 0.5, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0, NA, 0.125, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 
    0.3, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.5, 0.125, 0.25, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, NA), .Dim = c(21L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", 
        "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y", "NIL"), c("1", 
        "2", "3", "4", "5")))
```

I would like to assign the numbers from the `df1` to `df`. Column numbers(5 in total) of `df1` refer to letter positions. I would like to create a sliding window of 5 to assign the numbers from `df1`and then to sum the result and go through the whole `df`.

For example:

```
first 5 letters of `df`: PSEGR
assign numbers from `df1`: 0+0.45+0.125+0+0.125
summary of the first 5 numbers: 0.7
the next step:
letters from df: SEGRQ
assign numbers from `df1`:0.35+0.25+0.25+0.5+0.25
summary: 1.6 etc.
```

I tried the following code:

```
sliding_window_df <- rollapply(df, function(x) df1[cbind(match(x, rownames(df1)), 1:ncol(df1))],k=5, align="left", sum)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in trunc(width) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Would you suggest using a different more suitable function than rollapply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rolling operation try using `sapply` here :

```
n <- 1:ncol(df1)
sapply(seq_along(df), function(x) 
       sum(df1[cbind(match(df[x:(x+4)], rownames(df1)),n)], na.rm = TRUE))

# [1] 0.700 1.600 0.875 0.375 0.320 1.050 0.575 1.000 0.575 0.875
#[11] 0.575 0.600 0.750 0.750 0.725 0.405 0.625 0.525 1.075 0.850
#[21] 0.850 0.475 0.475 0.415 1.025 0.375 0.850 0.155 0.740 1.290
#[31] 0.775 0.865 0.775 1.000 0.350 1.380 0.250 0.450 0.655 0.250
#[41] 0.125 0.725 0.125 0.200 0.000
```